# GoogleMap Route from Two Points

Tags: google-maps, routes, marker

I was having some problem when trying to understand the codes which I get online to perform routing from one point to another. Here is the modified version of mine. The first portion is the initialization of map:

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
function initialize() {
var rendererOptions = {
    draggable : true
};
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
var mapOptions = {
    center : {
        lat : 1.32814,
        lng : 103.80679
    },
    zoom : 11
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
getRouteDirection();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This method will be executed once the map finish initializing:

```
function getRouteDirection() {
var htmlStr = "<div style='background: linear-gradient(#848484, #2E2E2E);color: white;line-height:2.2em;padding-left:5%;width:auto;font-weight:bold;'>Get Directions";
htmlStr += "<input id='calcRoutebtn' type='button' value='Calculate' onClick='calcRoute()' />";
htmlStr += "<div id='directionsPanel'></div>";
htmlStr += "</div><br/>";
document.getElementById("divGetRouteDirection").innerHTML = htmlStr;
}
```

When button on click, it will execute this function:

```
function calcRoute() {
var travelMode = 'TRANSIT';
var start = document.getElementById('startLoc').value;
var end = document.getElementById('endLoc').value;
var request = {
    origin : start,
    destination : end,
    unitSystem : google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[travelMode]
};
directionsService
        .route(
                request,
                function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        // document.getElementById('directionsPanel').empty();
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    } else {
                        if (status == 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                            alert('No route could be found between the origin and destination.');
                        } else if (status == 'UNKNOWN_ERROR') {
                            alert('A directions request could not be processed due to a server error. The request may succeed if you try again.');
                        } else if (status == 'REQUEST_DENIED') {
                            alert('This webpage is not allowed to use the directions service.');
                        } else if (status == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {
                            alert('The webpage has gone over the requests limit in too short a period of time.');
                        } else if (status == 'NOT_FOUND') {
                            alert('At least one of the origin, destination, or waypoints could not be geocoded.');
                        } else if (status == 'INVALID_REQUEST') {
                            alert('The DirectionsRequest provided was invalid.');
                        } else {
                            alert("There was an unknown error in your request. Requeststatus: nn"
                                    + status);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

}

With these, I managed to plot the routes between two points. However, I not sure which part of the code set the route color and as well as the marker symbol. Also, with these codes, it supposed to have something at the directionPanels but somehow, it does not appear.

I got my reference from [Tutorial](http://dreamdealer.nl/tutorials/adding_travel_modes_and_waypoints_to_google_maps_directions.html)  . The working example is inside that website. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the route may be set via the `polylineOptions`-property of rendererOptions, the marker via the `markerOptions` e.g.:

```
   var rendererOptions = {
    draggable : true,
    polylineOptions:{
      strokeColor:'red'
    },
    markerOptions:{
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/arrow.png'
    }
   };
```

Note that you can't define different markers for e.g. start and end, to achieve this you must disable the markers for the DirectionsRender and create your own marker based on the returned route.

The directionsPanel is not visible because the node(`div#directionsPanel`) doesn't exist at the moment when you set the directionsPanel. You create the node in `getRouteDirection`, so set the panel at the end of this function instead.

Comment: I see. It's working now. However, how do I disable the markers for the directions render?

Comment: Set the option `suppressMarkers` of `rendererOptions` to `true` . See: [**directionsRenderer-options**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#DirectionsRendererOptions)

Comment: As for the dotted line like walking path, what do we called it to change the color?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible via the options. You would have to disable the polylines too and draw them on your own. For the walking-part you may draw a dashed line(see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#dashed_lines )